# P2 Update Site not reachable under some network condition from maven/tycho build

Tags: maven, tycho, p2

We are using `maven`/`tycho` for our build.

The target platform can be resolved just fine if I am not in my company's VPN.
If VPN is on, then one repository cannot be resolved and the build shows:

```
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition <my-target-location>: Failed to load p2 metadata repository from location https://<some-p2-repo>: Unable to read repository at https://<some-p2-repo>/content.xml. Connection reset
```

First I thought that the repository may not be reachable from some IP addresses, but with a webbrowser I am able to access /content.jar (content.xml is missing, but as far as I understand this is okay if content.jar is there)

Comment: Is there a mirror configured in Maven (settings.xml)?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this by upgrading from Java version 11.0.9 to 11.0.15. Maybe, there was some SSL related limitation in 11.0.9.